# How do I allow a tweet to go through after an admin's approval?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I have a Rails 3 application and I allow users to make posts. These posts also get tweeted into their Twitter account using the Twitter gem.

The Posts table has a "verify" column inside it which defaults to false, however certain posts will get flagged as true. I have this in place so that certain posts will have to be verified by an admin user.

Here's what the schema.db code looks like:

```
create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "verify",          :default => false
```

This is how `verify` is defined inside my `Posts` controller:

```
def verify
  @post = post.find(params[:id])
  @post.verify = false
  @post.save
  redirect_to "/verify"
end
```

I am trying to add a variation of the two lines below inside `verify` so that an admin can use it.  It works when the user who made the post calls it, but not when an admin tries. I get an `undefined method 'update' for nil:NilClass`.

```
  @twitter_user = current_user.twitter_user
  @twitter_user.update(@post.content)
```

Here's how `twitter_user` is defined:

```
def twitter_user
    provider = self.authentications.find_by_provider('twitter')
    Twitter::Client.new(:oauth_token => provider.token, 
                        :oauth_token_secret => provider.secret)
  rescue
    return nil
  end
```

How should the code below be changed so that I can put it inside `verify` so admin can run it, while allowing the post to go to each poster's Twitter account?

```
  @twitter_user = current_user.twitter_user
  @twitter_user.update(@post.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you're currently loading the twitter user based on the `current_user`, if you run it as an admin it would presumably try and post the tweets as belonging to the admin. You should be able to fix the problem by changing the code used to post the tweets to:

```
@twitter_user = User.find(@post.user_id).twitter_user
@twitter_user.update(@post.content)
```

Comment: I know that it shouldn't be current_user when an admin tries to run it... your answer gives me `undefined method 'user_id' for nil:NilClass`. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Are you certain the post is getting loaded properly? In your `verify` method, you use `@post = post.find(params[:id])`, are you sure that shouldn't be `@post = Post.find(params[:id])` (with a capital 'P')?

Comment: yea the posts definitely are getting loaded properly; I accidentally typed it in lowercase. I'm just trying to figure out how to get the `@twitter_user` code lines to work if an admin runs them

Comment: Assuming `.twitter_user` belongs to the `User` class, it shouldn't make any difference if it's being run by a user or admin, right? The `undefined method 'user_id' for nil:NilClass` sounds like `@post` is nil, is it definitely loading properly for admin users as well?